# Bootcamp "No Bootable device" but windows already installed

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, partition

I had an issue in OSX which meant that I had to erase the OSX partition, and after reinstalling OSX, my bootcamp partition won't load. It's not in the option menu on start up, but is still recognised in `start up disk` and `disk utility`. I selected it in `startup disk` but I got there error mentioned in the title. I can see all my files in finder, but just can't boot into windows. Anyone know what's going on?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the partition MBR was wiped on the erase and the entire disk became a single GPT with a single hybrid MBR. I had for recreate the Hybrid MBR using FDISK.